# A tricky one involving List<T> and object casting

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance, casting

I was given this question at a job interview recently and couldn't figure out how to do it elegantly. Ever since, it has been nagging away at me and I can't work out if its a lack of knowledge about some 'modern' technique/technology I'm unaware of or if I'm just stupid. Any advice would be very welcome.

#### The Problem

Imagine a simple class hierarchy:

```
abstract class Person {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Child : Person { }

class Parent : Person {
    public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
}

class Ancestor : Parent { }
```

The problem is how to traverse a hierarchy of such objects and to print out all the people encountered. So for the following scenario:

```
Ancestor myAncestor = new Ancestor {    
    Name = "GrandDad",
    Children = new List<Person> { 
        new Child { Name = "Aunt" },
        new Child { Name = "Uncle" },
        new Parent {
            Name = "Dad", 
            Children = new List<Person> { 
                new Child { Name = "Me" }, 
                new Child { Name = "Sister" } 
            }
        }
    }
};
```

the output should be something like:

```
GrandDad  
-    Aunt  
-    Uncle  
-    *Dad  
         -Me  
         -Sister
```

All the processing needs to be done within a single method that accepts a single parameter of type `Ancestor`.

I implemented, almost without thinking, a simple recursive solution but of course because of the way the objects involved relate to each other things aren't as simple as all that.

Try as I might I cannot think of a clean way of doing this and my post-interview Googlings have suggested I need to be doing something that is (to me, with only a working knowledge of `LINQ` and `List<T>`) something considerably more technically advanced than the sort of web-dev coding I've been doing for the last decade or so. Is this the case? Or should I be thinking of getting out of software development on the grounds that I'm rubbish at it?

#### Update

Thanks to you all for your responses/suggestions. I've accepted @Daniel Hilgarth's answer primarily because it was the only one I could genuinely understand :-o

Comment: Can you add methods to the classes?

Comment: Personally, I think whoever designed that type system needs a slap. There is (or rather, should be) no type-specific different in the role of an `Ancestor`, `Parent` or `Child`... just sayin'

Comment: if the method has to accept an ancestor and the hierachi of objects has only an ancestor at the root how would you do that recursively? or is there something I'm not getting or incoorectly stated?

Comment: @RuneFS an ancestor is a parent, and a parent has children

Comment: @MarcGravell yes but a parent is not an ancestor (sic!) so you can't pass the parent as an argument to a mehtod that accepts only ancestors

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - nope. You're only allowed to modify the code in a single method e.g. `void PrintFamily(Ancestor a)`.

Comment: @RuneFS ah, right - I see what you mean; yes, indeed that can't be recursive method invocation, but can still be recursive *in terms of the model*

Comment: Perhaps you were actually expected to complain that it was a good design and propose an alternative?

Comment: @Miquel - I did exactly that! But they were definitely expecting a concrete solution to this :-(

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett - No, you're only allowed to write one method with that signature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with Marc's comment saying that this type system is non-sense. Still, you can solve it with delegates. That's a bit of cheating, because basically they are nothing more than  methods, but here we go:

```
void PrintFamily(Ancestor a)
{
    Action<Parent, int> printParent = null;
    printParent = (parent, level) => 
    {
        var indentation = new string(' ', level * 4);
        var indentationChildren = new string(' ', (level + 1) * 4);
        Console.WriteLine(indentation + parent.Name);
        foreach(var child in parent.Children)
        {
            if(child is Child)
                Console.WriteLine(indentationChildren + child.Name);
            else if(child is Parent)
            {
                printParent((Parent)child, level + 1);
            }
        }
    };

    printParent(a, 0);
}
```

Comment: +1 Clever use of delegates to get around the requirements. Hopefully it's not considered cheating! :)

Comment: You could use `new string(char, count)` instead of `enumerable.repeat` though.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Thanks for the hint. That's much better

Comment: I feel a bit better because I'd never have got that in a million years due to my ignorance of the `Action` delegate. Perhaps I'm not as code-stupid as I feared, but commonsense stupid enough not to keep up to speed with the .Net framework. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

This is horrible, but within the scope of the question (no extra methods, so can't add polymorphism/discriminator, and method must take `Ancestor`, so no method recursion):

```
static void Write(Ancestor root)
{
    // stack since depth-first
    var stack = new Stack<Tuple<Person,int>>();
    stack.Push(Tuple.Create((Person)root, 0));

    while(stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var pair= stack.Pop();
        var person = pair.Item1;

        // indentation
        Console.Write(new string('\t', pair.Item2));
        Parent parent = person as Parent;

        // node markers aren't fully specified, but this gets somewhere
        // near; maybe * should actually be checking Children != null &&
        // Children.Count > 0             
        if(person == root) {}
        else if (parent != null) { Console.Write("*");}
        else {Console.Write("-");}            

        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);

        // recursion on the stack
        if(parent != null && parent.Children != null) {
            foreach(var next in Enumerable.Reverse(parent.Children)) {
                stack.Push(Tuple.Create(next, pair.Item2 + 1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my go, using a stack to emulate recursion:

```
static void PrintTree(Ancestor ancestor)
{
    Stack<Tuple<int, Person>> PersonStack = new Stack<Tuple<int, Person>>();
    PersonStack.Push(new Tuple<int, Person>(0, ancestor));

    while (PersonStack.Count != 0)
    {
        Tuple<int, Person> NextPerson = PersonStack.Pop();

        Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', NextPerson.Item1) + NextPerson.Item2.Name);

        Parent NextPersonAsParent = NextPerson.Item2 as Parent;
        if (NextPersonAsParent != null && NextPersonAsParent.Children != null)
        {
            foreach (var Child in NextPersonAsParent.Children)
            {
                PersonStack.Push(new Tuple<int, Person>(NextPerson.Item1 + 1, Child));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
internal void ToString(Ancestor root)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(root.Name);
    Trace.Indent();
    foreach(var child in root.Children)
    {
         if(child is Parent)
             ToString(new Ancestor(){Name = child.Name, 
                                     Children = ((Parent)child).Children});
         else
             Trace.WriteLine(child.Name);
    }
    Trace.Unindent();
}
```

Comment: personally i think this solution is the best.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek - could you please elaborate why you think so?

Comment: @5arx Your comment made me look at this again. I think it's clear to see that IF the requirement for a single Ancestor parameter was in fact part of the interview question (and not just an interview jitters oversight (happens to the best of us)), there are only two possible conclusions to be made: Either the interviewer made a mistake and didn't think it through, or they wanted you to see the mistake and tell them why it didn't make sense.

Comment: No jitters, the problem was stated in print (I still have it in fact) and I quoted it in the question. I don't suppose it was intended to simulate a real-world scenario, just contrived to assess candidates' depth of knowledge of C#.

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit of "cheating" (thanks daniel for the ides" this uses recursion and stays with in the constraints of the task.

**DISCLAIMER** this more proves that the class hierachi proposed is odd. Especially for the task and I wouldn't use this technique in production

```
  internal static string ToString(Ancestor root){
        Func<Parent, string, string> inner = (x, y) => string.Empty;
        inner = (p, indentation) =>{
                    var parents = p.Children.OfType<Parent>();
                    var children = p.Children.OfType<Child>();
                    var childString =
                        string.Concat
                            (children.Select
                                 (c => indentation + "-" + c.Name + Environment.NewLine));
                    return indentation + "-" + p.Name + Environment.NewLine +
                           childString +
                           string.Concat
                               (parents.Select(par => inner(par, " " + indentation)));
                };
        return inner(root, string.Empty);
    }
```

Firstly we declare a functor and initialize with a dummy value.

Then we construct a lambda expression that can call it self recursively. The body of the expression does the same as the below method.

If the method signatur did not require an ancestor we could have done something like:

```
    internal string ToString(Parent parent, string indentation){
        var parents = parent.Children.OfType<Parent>();
        var children = parent.Children.OfType<Child>();
        var childString = children.Select(c => indentation + "-" + c.Name + Environment.NewLine);
        return indentation + "-" + parent.Name + Environment.NewLine + childString +
               string.Concat(parents.Select(par => ToString(par, " " + indentation)));
    }
```

first create a list of all parent and one of all children. Then create the string for all the children (where no recursion is needed) and the recurs for all parents

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

A polymorphic solution is most likely the simplest, but you need to be able to alter the objects. Have `Person` implement a virtual method: `Print()` for instance, which would be overridden in `Parent` in order to printout the children. Indentation could be handled by supplying an indentation-level argument for instance. ***As you have noted, the constraints of the problem prohibit this***.

The object structure provided in the question is rather senseless, and the constraints rather narrow. Also, the fact that you need to implement a method that takes an `Ancestor` and are limited to only that method body, leads me to think that the question was asked specifically to lead you towards the stack approach. Additionally, the latter has important performance benefits when compared to recursion.

There are a couple of good stack examples already, so I would suggest an alternate recursion approach, that in principle should fit the 'don't declare any extra methods'-rule, and is much more readable ( if you know your lambda's :)

```
Action<IEnumerable<Person>, int> traverseAndPrint = null;
traverseAndPrint =
    (ps, i) =>
    {
        foreach (var p in ps)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}-{1}", new string(' ', i), p.Name);

            if (p is Parent) traverseAndPrint(((Parent)p).Children, i + 1);
        }
    };

traverseAndPrint(new [] {ancestor}, 0);
```

Comment: Altering the objects is not an option. Can you elaborate on the recursion and stack--based solutions please? The other, no doubt excellent responses are way over my head :-(

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to (re)create objects and exploit their simplicity you could use this:

```
    private static void PrintAncestor(Ancestor myAncestor)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(myAncestor.Name);
        foreach (var child in myAncestor.Children)
        {
            string intend = new string(myAncestor.Name.TakeWhile(c => c == '\t').ToArray()) + '\t';

            if (child is Ancestor)
                PrintAncestor(new Ancestor {
                    Children = (child as Ancestor).Children,
                    Name = intend + child.Name
                });

            if (child is Parent)
                PrintAncestor(new Ancestor {
                    Children = (child as Parent).Children,
                    Name = intend + "- *" + child.Name
                });

            if (child is Child)
                Console.WriteLine(intend + "-  " + child.Name);
        }
    }
```

prints:

```
GrandDad
        -  Aunt
        -  Uncle
        - *Dad
                -  Me
                -  Sister
```